# Iterating through vtkFloatArray

Tags: c++, vtk

I noticed that the return type of a function I'm calling is `vtkFloatArray`. I want to check the components of this array, but, not sure how to iterate through its components.

Since when I tried to iterate through the elements, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'vtkobject' object is not iterable
```

Why am I getting such error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If your array is not a tuple :

```
float value;
for(int i = 0; i < array->GetNumberOfTuples(); i++)
{
    value = array->GetValue(i);
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

if your array is a tuple of size 3 :

```
double * values;
for(int i = 0; i < array->GetNumberOfTuples(); i++)
{
    values = array->GetTuple3(i);
    std::cout << values[0] << " " << values[1] << " " << values[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of components and number of tuples of the array, and then, for example, call repeatedly getTuple http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataArray.html#aca11c70280dad75aabbe5747c55c6919

You can also have a look at vtkDataArrayIteratorMacro http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataArrayIteratorMacro.html#details